# Replacing links in html with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using some JS code to find all internal links on a page and add a subfolder to them.  This code is used on translated pages so internal links to other translated pages are correct.

I want to have this code update all internal links, unless they have a class attribute.

If the class attribute exists, I want the link to be ignored by the JavaScript function.

```
<a class="noTranslateLink" href="domain.com"
```

---

```
<script>
    function replace_url(elem, attr) {
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
            elems[i][attr] = elems[i][attr].replace('<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>', '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/ru');
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        replace_url('a', 'href');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested, But this must work:

```
function replace_url(elem, attr) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].getAttribute('class') != "noTranslateLink")
      elems[i].setAttribute(attr,elems[i].setAttribute(attr).replace('',''));

  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, nice and simple. swap == for != to reverse condition. Great, thanks!

Comment: Oh Yes, that was a tyop. Let me edit this in the answer :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To select all anchor elements with no class attribute:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(elem + ':not([class])');
```

The opposite is:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(elem + '[class]');
```

Comment: Thanks, hover it seems to work the same as my code.

 `<script>
 function replace_url(elem, attr) {
     var elems = document.querySelectorAll(elem + ':not([noTranslate])');
     for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
         elems[i][attr] = elems[i][attr].replace('<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>', '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/ru');
 }
 window.onload = function() {
     replace_url('a', 'href');
 }
</script> `